# TCL: Cannot open a program with "exec" command

Tags: file, vim, tcl

Try to open a file with gvim.exe in tcl. I have correctly installed gvim but cannot open it with the following 2 command:

```
exec gvim.exe $file_path
exec ./gvim.exe $file_path
```

However, is able to open the file with the following 2 commands:

```
exec notepad.exe $file_path
exec "C:/Program Files/vim/vim74/gvim.exe
```

Could somebody tell me what happened and what I should do here?

Comment: Add `%ProgramFiles%/vim/vim74` to your `%PATH%`

Answer (score 2):

When Tcl `exec`s a program, it searches for the program on your `PATH` (i.e., `$::env(PATH)`) using the OS's normal rules. Programs not on the `PATH` (and not in the current directory on Windows) are simply not found.

### Fix 1

Update your `PATH`; I believe you can do this through the Control Panel on a per-user basis, or for all users (with appropriate permissions).

### Fix 2

Update the `PATH` in your script. Be aware that the Windows path separator is a command separator in Tcl (i.e., needs to be escaped or come from substitution) and the elements in the `PATH` need to be *native* directory names.

```
append ::env(PATH) $::tcl_platform(pathSeparator) \
        [file nativename "C:/Program Files/vim/vim74"]

## This will do the same thing...
# append ::env(PATH) {;C:\Program Files\vim\vim74}
```